# No filtering autocomplete with json_encode

Tags: php, json

I had this in test.php

```
echo json_encode(filter_unique_array($arrayList,'FRUIT'));
```

Result of test.php when run is

["Apple","Orange","Pear","Watermelon","Pineapple"]

In HTML I have this

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
            source: 'test.php',
            minLength: 3
                });

<INPUT id =input>
```

but the input text does not able to filter out what I type. It just display all the records from the test.php
Example when I type pp, apple and pineapple shall be my end result but in this case all 5 fruits appear. 
What is wrong? Is the reult of my test.php wrong?

Comment: You have to do the filtering on the server, all the records you send will be displayed

Comment: How did this website did it without sending any filtering to filter?http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote.html

Comment: It does, why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: which part of the line did the filteriing?

Comment: The filtering is done on their server, they send `term=filtersstr` to their server and return an array of items that contain `filterstring`. In your case when you type in `pp` your server should check all terms against `$_GET['term']` and filter them, returning `["Apple","Pineapple"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After many testing I get it with $_GET["term"].

Answer (score 0):

seems your syntax error, should be `$("#input")`